# Why is my code so slow?

Tags: python, time, cprofile

I'm new to cProfile.

I ran cProfile on my program and it spit out this:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1  290.732  290.732  313.069  313.069 newad.py:1(<module>)
```

The first line of newad.py is:

```
1  from datetime import date
```

Is this line supposed to take this much time?  What can I do instead?

Comment: How did you run cProfile? Does your module contain anything other than an import statement?

Comment: @PeterGibson I ran cProfile again.  This time it identified the import statement as taking the most time.  I'm editing the question.

Comment: if this result is considered "wrong", what result did you expect or hope for instead?

Comment: @PeterGibson And there is of course other code within the module, but cProfile says the rest takes a negligible amount of time to run.

Comment: @Deestan I was hoping for the line to take less time than 290 seconds.  However, I don't know if this is typical of importing date from datetime.  This is the first time I've run cProfile on my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cProfile is just showing you the time spent in that module. The line number seems to just indicate the first statement processed in that module - because you have a multiline docstring, it shows the last line of the docstring.

```
"""
Test module for cProfile stats

"""



import time

def wait(t):
    time.sleep(t)

wait(5)
```

Gives:

```
   $ python -m cProfile test.py
         4 function calls in 5.002 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.001    5.001 test.py:10(wait)
        1    0.001    0.001    5.002    5.002 test.py:4(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    5.001    5.001    5.001    5.001 {time.sleep}
```

Note the first line shows the time spent in the funciton `wait` while the second line shows the time spent in the module.

Comment: Thanks!  I was going crazy trying to figure out why this wasn't working.  Now to optimize the code within the module...